# Will Apple accept my app if I disable Sign in with Third parties

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, app-store

Apple just rejected my app due to I don't offer Sign in with Apple in my app as my app allow login with Google and Linkedin, and these(sign in with Google and Linkedin) are configurable like if some user don't want this it'll be disable by Admin.
So Can I go with another try to remove this option for that user which we give to Apple for Review and also tell them its configurable and not mandatory. So will Apple accept my app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Personally I do not recommend using different configurations only for the App Store review process, because you can get rejected from App Store completely for cheating on the process. Read more at:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#introduction

> If you attempt to cheat the system (for example, by trying to trick
> the review process, steal user data, copy another developer’s work,
> manipulate ratings or App Store discovery) your apps will be removed
> from the store and you will be expelled from the Apple Developer
> Program.

About Apple Sign, here is Apple guidelines regarding this feature:

**4.8 Sign in with Apple**

> Apps that exclusively use a third-party or social login service (such
> as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with
> LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or
> authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer
> Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account
> is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of
> identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and
> associated services.

Sign in with Apple is not required if:

- Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and
  sign-in systems.
- Your app is an education, enterprise, or business
  app that requires the user to sign in with an existing education or
  enterprise account.
- Your app uses a government or industry-backed
  citizen identification system or electronic ID to authenticate users.
- Your app is a client for a specific third-party service and users are
  required to sign in to their mail, social media, or other third-party
  account directly to access their content.

Read more:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple

Comment: Thanks for brief answer, actually there is no intention to cheat but to tell Apple that these third party configration aren't hard & fast. User can change or remove depend upon configuration on Admin side as we are selling deployent of server with that server our app work accordingly, so many user don't like these third parties so they can remove those.